# Wrongly classified cases in a binary classification challenge (in keras)

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

The below defined neural network is used in order to classify the dataset seen in the image: [image].
Simulation statistics suggests that the classification accuracy is 50%, so my question is how do i know which cases of the dataset where not classified correctly?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("sorted output.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:3]
Y = dataset[:,3]
# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: What do you mean by simulation statistics? You can just call the predict method on your test or train data and then compare it to the ground truth.

Comment: I get a classification accuracy of 50% on my testing data (val_acc). This means that half of the test data is not classified correctly. I just whant to know which traces of my dataset where not correctly classified by the NN. Can you please be more specific? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `model.predict(X_train)` with `y_train`. In order to do that, you can add the rows

```
train_prediction=np.round(model.predict(X_train)).reshape(-1)
train_prediction=train_prediction.astype(int)
```

to the end of your code. Then you can look at the nonzero entries in `train_prediction-y_train`. The positions of these entries are the places where the model made missclassification.

The reason for the `np.round` is that your last activation function is sigmoid. This means that values that are closer to 0 are classified as 0, and those that are closer to 1 are classified as 1.